# Requiredfieldvalidator not allowing to go back from the page withouy filling hte required fields

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi i have an issue with my Required field validator.
I have two text boxes in the page which have requiredfieldvalidator on it. I also have a button on my page which will take the user back to previous page. When i land into this page and click on the back button it shows the requiredfieldvalidator issue on the text boxes.So to go back to the previous page i have to enter some value on the text boxes which is not much user friendly.
Am i supposed to use some-other validator?
Appreciate your help .

Comment: Are you using CausesValidation="false" on your back button definition . It helped me to solve he issue by bypassing the button from validation.

Comment: A requiredfieldvalidator acts when the page does postback, and that is the default behavior of a button and another controls, the use of CausesValidation is effective, the problem is the other controls that make postback, you would perform the validation in the click event of the button that gives access  if exist.

Comment: I found an msdn page and it worked. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.causesvalidation.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we set a  RequiredFieldValidator it is appplicable for the whole section not just the textbox or something.
I need to escape from the validation and.

[Description][1]
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.causesvalidation.aspx

use CausesValidation="false" to the button and the button will be able to escape the validation.